# Going through annotations in Okular

Tags: kde, pdf, okular, annotation

I use Okular to read and annotate PDF textbooks. I use mostly highlighting alone but I sometimes add a pop-up note attached to highlighted text. When I want to read some material again, I like to just go through my annotations: I open the navigation panel, I go to reviews and I start browsing. When I highlighted something, the navigation panel does not tell me whether I attached a pop-up note to it. When I click on the corresponding annotation, it does not open the pop-up note either. I have to manually right-click on the annotation, click "open pop-up note", to find 90% of the time that I did not write anything. I think it greatly limits the benefit of annotations in the first place.

Is there a way in Okular to have pop-up notes open automatically when reviewing annotations? The question also concerns standalone pop-up notes, not only the ones attached to highlighted text. If not, any advice on what PDF reader/editor to use in Ubuntu with which I could get such a behavior?

Linux version: Ubuntu 18.04; 
Okular version: 1.3.3.

Comment: No, I don't think this is possible in Okular, but is a feature I would also like to have. Or even better, having the pop-up text displayed directly in the annotations pane.